# 2 dependent autocomplete field in CCK

Tags: 7, ajax

I have 2 autocomplete (`autocomplete1` and `autocomplete2`) field in a content type. I need to make one of them depend on the other one
I make a `hook_form_alter` to change the path of the `autocomplete2`

I used Ajax when changing `autocomplete1` and return `autocomplete2` by change the `autocomplete_path` but it did not work.

This is my code

```
function myhook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if($form_id == 'x'){
    $form['field_sub_news_name']['#prefix'] = '<div id="subnews_autocomplete">';
    $form['field_sub_news_name']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['field_main_news_name']['und'][0]['nid']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_change_autocomplete_subnews_field',
      'wrapper' => 'subnews_autocomplete',
      'method' => 'html',
      'effect' => 'fade'
    );
}
```

}

```
function ajax_change_autocomplete_subnews_field($form, $form_state) {
$nid = $form_state['values']['field_tadwena_main_news_name']['und'][0]['nid'];
$form['field_tadwena_sub_news_name']['und'][0]['nid']['#autocomplete_path'] = "/ajax/autocomplete_subnews_field_path/$nid"; 
return $form['field_tadwena_sub_news_name'];
```

}

I tried to use `$form['field_tadwena_sub_news_name']['und'][0]['nid']['#autocomplete_input']['#url_value'] = "ajax/autocomplete_subnews_field_path/$nid";`  but it gives me a JavaScript error

I hope someone can help me